macOS refusing to use my primary dns server (dnsmasq on same network)
I run dnsmasq 2.89 to resolve IPs for local services on my network. I use DHCP to set the primary DNS server IP to my dnsmasq instance, and the primary to Cloudflare DNS. I am using macOS 14.3.1 as my desktop OS. Looking at the network configuration gui, resolv.conf, and scutil --dns, the DNS settings match what I would expect.
(I have trimmed the comments from resolv.conf and the mDNS/reverse DNS entries from scutil output)

❯ scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : local
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.50.10
  nameserver[1] : 1.1.1.1
  if_index : 12 (en0)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : local
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.50.10
  nameserver[1] : 1.1.1.1
  if_index : 12 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

❯ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search local
nameserver 192.168.50.10
nameserver 1.1.1.1

Also when using dig, I am able to use my dnsmasq server to resolve the names that I expect to resolve in the rest of the system (yes I'm aware that I'm using a public domain name but I own this domain name and I want to use it within my home network)
❯ dig synology.lilys.hair

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> synology.lilys.hair
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 1334
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;synology.lilys.hair.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
synology.lilys.hair.    0   IN  A   192.168.50.10

;; Query time: 10 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.50.10#53(192.168.50.10)
;; WHEN: Mon May 13 16:51:58 PDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64

Despite this, when I attempt to use my web browser or cURL to navigate to this host, DNS resolution fails. I attempted to diagnose this by clearing my DNS cache then starting Wireshark and attempting to use cURL to connect. Wireshark showed no DNS query for my desired host, other than the dig query that I issued after verifying cURL made no such query.
❯ sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

❯ curl synology.lilys.hair
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: synology.lilys.hair

❯ dig synology.lilys.hair

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> synology.lilys.hair
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6518
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
...


The lone DNS request/response cycle in this screenshot indicate the communications that dig made, they were not created by cURL, and indeed no (traditional) DNS queries were sent out by cURL for this domain name.
If I remove the Cloudflare DNS server from the list of DNS servers, then I am able to resolve my domain name locally with no issues, but ideally I would still have this fallback configured locally so that queries do not fail if my local dnsmasq instance goes down.
I have to assume that cURL and Chrome are noticing that my local server does not speak some more-secure dns-over-https or dnssec protocol that I'm not privy to overriding myself. How can I tell my OS to trust my home DNS server (even if just for this 2ld) without having to resort to removing Cloudflare as a fallback DNS?

You can't do what you want with macOS' DNS resolver, because it doesn't treat the DNS server list as having any sort of priority (see "macOS High Sierra not trying other DNS servers"). If you give it multiple DNS servers, it just distributes queries between all of them. I don't know why you didn't see another query after HUPping mDNSResponder; was WireShark listening for queries to 1.1.1.1 as well as 192.168.50.10?

Dang, that's a bit frustrating, but it makes sense. I've seen intermittent success, so it must be balancing requests rather than prioritizing based on the list. WireShark should have captured the queries to 1.1.1.1, it was capturing all traffic on the only network interface connected to the Internet and I started it before I reset mDNSResponder. Very strange.
